# React Redux - How do I build a form with material-ui that I can add inputs to?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am in the process of refactoring code from a React-Flux-Bootstrap app to Redux with Material-ui. What I would really like to do is have a form that starts with one input to begin with (i.e. title) and then be able to add multiple extra inputs by clicking on a button. These inputs will all be the same but obviously will need to be differentiated between (i.e. name).

Ideally I would like to be able to be able to enter in as many names as I want, collect them as an array and then send them back to my database. I am more concerned with actually creating the form itself and the code for collecting the inputs.

If someone could give me a quick example as to how I might start going about achieving this I would very much appreciate it!

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The React "comments" tutorial has a good example of user input driving a growing list: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html. You want to look at the CommentList class.

To data drive the list of form fields, you could do something like this:

```
getInitialState() {
  return {
    formFields: [{key: "one", value: "first"}, {key: "two", value: "second"}]
  }
},

getOnChange(key) {
  let handler = () => {
    let newValue = this.refs[key].getValue()
    let newState = {}
    newState[key] = newValue
    this.setState(newState)
  }
  return handler
},

render() {
  return (
    <Paper>
      {this.state.formFields.map((item, index) => {
        return (<TextField ref={item.key} key={item.key} defaultValue={item.value} onChange={this.getOnChange(item.key)}/>)
      })}
    </Paper>
  )
}
```

I used a closure for onChange to demonstrate variability, but there are other ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Hi Larry, what I am trying to do is slightly different in that I want to generate multiple inputs on the form. I suspect that I will implement something similar to that tutorial when it comes to posting the data to the server (so thanks for pointing me to that) but could you point me towards something that would help me generate a form which I can add a dynamic amount of inputs to? As I am refactoring flux code I could use that as a basis but it uses bootstrap not material-ui and the code is a bit of a mess!

Comment: OIC. I updated my answer with a way to do that. The key is to use the Array.map() function.

Comment: @BeeNag, did this help? If so, can you please accept the answer?

Comment: Hi Larry sorry I haven't replied sooner! That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for your help!